# Change width of selected text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an HTML block

```
<div id="container">
<div id="box"><p>message</p></div>
</div>
```

When I use the cursor to select the text, the area highlighted is **"container"** instead of just **"box"** or **"p"**.

I tried using CSS ::selection/::-moz-selection to control the width, but this seems to only change the highlight colour...

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "width"? Do you want text to be larger or gain some padding when selected, or do you mean something else?

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of this? I really can't imagine what you mean.

Comment: What browser? I'm not seeing that behavior.

Comment: Sorry, added a screenshot. The green is the "selected" text area but the <p> is the white area inside the box.

Comment: I still don't really understand what you're asking. Could you describe the set-up, what action the user performs to trigger the desired behaviour, what the desired behaviour is and what you actually see?

Comment: If the user goes and selects "You have been invited" with their mouse/cursor, the selected area is the green area which goes **outside** of the white box...which looks totally bad. It would be nice if the green area stays **inside** of the white box.

Comment: Post the rest of your HTML/JS/CSS so we can see what's really going on. Your screenshot and description don't have enough detail.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the css seems to work:

```
#box {
display: inline-block;
}
```

But if anyone else has other suggestions...